# Unable to set Android webview width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I have been trying to add a Webview control to my Android app on a screen using TableLayout
Unfortunately whatever i try, the webview always covers the whole width of the screen
 The layout file contains the following code

```
<TableRow android:layout_gravity="center">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/someid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="100dp">
    </WebView>
</TableRow>
```

The Activity file contains the following

```
@Override protected void onFinishInflate(){

    WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
    mywebView.setScrollContainer(false);
    mywebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(context), "Android");

}
```

Is there any specific reason why the control would always cover the whole screen width. The height attribute seems to work but whatever I use for `android:layout_width` the width is always 100% of screen width.
I have tried giving a fixed value to `android:layout_width` as well as multiple combinations of the websettings in the java file.

Any clues why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define at first the parameters of your `tableRow`. For example:
    layout_width and layout_height inside `tableRow`:

```
<TableRow android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="100dp">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/someid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</WebView>
```

Comment: using this, hides the webview all together. maybe because the content of the webview is being loaded dynamically using JS.Its sort of a google adsense like js, which loads the actual content after the page has loaded!Changing the webview height to 100dp makes the webview to appear again but the width becomes 100%

Answer (score -1):

Strangely, wrappping the control in a LinearLayout fixed the issue

```
  <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
     <WebView
        android:id="@+id/someid"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_width="250px"
         android:orientation="vertical" 
        >
     </WebView>
  </LinearLayout>
```